# Perl: How to consider next XML tag as child tag of previous one?

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, xml-twig

In following data file, I want to consider each `<Field>` tag as child tag of `<Register>` and each `<Register>` as child of `<Partition>`. so, basically, I am trying to extract each `<Partition>` details with corresponding `<Register>` and `<Field>`. Since all these tags are separate and not as child-parent relationship, how can I get my desired output?

Since the file is very large, I do not want to make it as child-parent relationship as it will require find/replace and manual intervention.

```
<Partition>
    <Name>1</Name>
    <Abstract>2</Abstract>
    <Description>3</Description>
    <ParentName>4</ParentName>

    </Partition>
    <Partition>
    <Name>8</Name>
    <Abstract></Abstract>
    <Description>9</Description>
    <ParentName>10</ParentName>

    </Partition>
    <Register>
    <Name>12</Name>
    <Abstract></Abstract>
    <Description>13</Description>
    <ParentName>14</ParentName>

    <Size>32</Size>
    <AccessMode>15</AccessMode>
    <Type>16</Type>


    </Register>
    <Field>
    <Name>17</Name>
    <Abstract></Abstract>
    <Description></Description>
    <ParentName></ParentName>


    </Field>
    <Field>
    .
    .
    .
    </Field>
    <Register>
    .
    .
    .

    </Register>
    <Field>
    .
    .
    .

    </Field>
    <Field>
    .
    .
    .
    </Field>
    <Partition>
        <Name>88</Name>
        <Abstract></Abstract>
        <Description></Description>
        <ParentName>55</ParentName>

    </Partition>
    <Register>
        .
        .
        .

    </Register>
    <Field>
        .
        .
        .

    </Field>
    <Partition>
        .
        .
        .
    </Partition>
    <Partition>
        .
        .
        .
    </Partition>
    <Partition>
       .
       .
       .
    </Partition>
    <Register>
        .
        .
        .
    </Register>
```

I am using `XML::Twig` package and here is my code snippet:

```
foreach my $register ( $twig->get_xpath('//Register') ) # get each <Register>
    {
        #print $register, "\n";
        my $reg_name = $register->first_child('Name')->text;
        my $reg_abstract= $register->first_child('Abstract')->text;
        my $reg_description= $register->first_child('Description')->text;
       .
       .
       .
          foreach my $xml_field ($register->get_xpath('Field'))
          {
            my $reg_field_name= $xml_field->first_child('Name')->text;
            my $reg_field_abstract= $xml_field->first_child('Abstract')->text;
            #print "$reg_field_name \n";
            .
            .
            .

          }
  }
```

Comment: I agree they should be children, but they aren't. No amount of "considering" (whatever that means) is going to change that fact. Being siblings instead of children, isn't it simply a question of using `next_sibling` instead of `first_child`?

Comment: as ikegami says, `Register` and `Field` are not children of `Partition`. Also you seem to be loading the whole file in memory anyway. If the file is really big, what you could do is set up `twig_handlers` on all 3 tags, output/store the information based on the current element and the previous one(s), and purge the tree when you find a new `Partition`. Note that without proper test data it's difficult to give you a code example (notably I wonder if the parent/child relationship should not be defined by the `ParentName` element instead of the location of the elements in the XML)

Comment: That's good idea. How can I rewrite this file as parent-child relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, if you want to rewrite the file with `Register` and `Field` elements as children of `Partition` elements, here is what you could do:

simplest solution, the whole file is loaded in memory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $test_file= 'test.xml';

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 'Register|Field' => \&child,
                                 },
                pretty_print => 'indented',
              )
          ->parsefile( $test_file)
          ->print;

sub child
  { my( $t, $child)= @_;
    $child->move( last_child => $child->prev_sibling( 'Partition'));
  }
```

Since you mentioned that the file can be very large, below is a slightly more complex version that only keeps in memory 2 `Partition` elements (including the new children of the first one). When a `Partition` is parsed it uses `flush_up_to` to flush the tree, up to the previous `Partition`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $test_file= 'test.xml';

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 'Partition' => \&parent,
                                   'Register|Field' => \&child,
                                 },
                pretty_print => 'indented',
              )
          ->parsefile( $test_file);

sub child
  { my( $t, $child)= @_;
    $child->move( last_child => $child->prev_sibling( 'Partition'));
  }

sub parent
  { my( $t, $partition)= @_;
    if( my $prev_partition = $partition->prev_sibling( 'Partition'))
      { $t->flush_up_to( $prev_partition); }
  }
```

Note that since `flush_up_to` is used, at the end of the parsing the rest of the tree is automatically flushed

If you need to write the XML to a specific file, instead of STDOUT, you can also pass a filehandle to `flush_up_to`.

Comment: Thanks mirod!
I am facing this error: junk after document element at line 11, column 0, byte 333 at C:/Perl64/lib/XML/Parser.pm line 187.

`1. <Partition>
2. <Name>PP</Name>
3. <Abstract></Abstract>
4. <Description></Description>
5. <ParentName>sec</ParentName>
6. <StructureTag></StructureTag>
7. <AddressOffset>64</AddressOffset>
8. <NumberOfPartitions>1</NumberOfPartitions>
9. <IntervalBetweenPartitions>0</IntervalBetweenPartitions>
10. </Partition>
11. <Partition>
12. <Name>control_alarm_status</Name>
13. <Abstract></Abstract>
14. <Description>#</Description>`

Comment: Okay. It's resolved. Root element tag was missing in my file. Thanks @mirod.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, I have written very basic code to convert `Field` as a child to `Register` and `Register` as child to `Partition`:

```
use strict;
#use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper; 
use Data::Alias;

my $input_xml_file = "gpon.xml";

open (IN_FILE,$input_xml_file);
my @input_file = <IN_FILE>;


for (my $line=0;$line<@input_file;$line++)
{

            if ($input_file[$line] =~ /<\/Partition>/ && $input_file[$line+1] =~ /<Register>/)
            {
                $input_file[$line] = '';

            }
            if ($input_file[$line] =~ /<\/Field>/ && $input_file[$line+1] =~ /<Partition>/)
            {
                $input_file[$line] = "</Field>
</Register>
</Partition>
";

            }
            if ($input_file[$line] =~ /<\/Field>/ && $input_file[$line+1] =~ /<Register>/)
            {
                $input_file[$line] = "</Field>
</Register>
";

            }
            if ($input_file[$line] =~ /<\/Register>/ && $input_file[$line+1] =~ /<Field>/ )
            {
                $input_file[$line] = '';

            }

}
#print OUT_FILE "</Register>";


close(IN_FILE);
open (OUT_FILE,'>gpon_modified.xml');
foreach (@input_file)
{
     print OUT_FILE "$_";
}
print OUT_FILE "</Register>
</Partition>";
close (OUT_FILE);
```